# Is there a pythonic way to wrap a class using with statement?

Tags: python, wrapper, with-statement

I did the following, it works, but I have doubts on its robustness.

```
import B

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self._b = B()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self._b .__enter__()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return self._b .__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
```

I know the methods `B.__enter__()` and `B.__exit__()` should not be used outside B, but I did not find another way to do this.
Is it acceptable to wrap a class this this way?
Is there another way?

I am aware that the answer might be: "No, this is exactly what the `with` is meant to prevent"

Comment: In isolation, this would be elegant and obvious if A was a subclass of B.

Comment: What's the use case of this wrapper class? Why do you need it?

Comment: This is perfectly fine to *implement* a context manager. Depending on what you want to do, ``contextlib.contextmanager`` might do that for you, though.

Comment: @azro, no, I do not see information about wrapping there

Comment: blhsing, I need to instance the class B differently depending on parameters on the class A
@tripleee, I first overlooked this option because of the above reason, but we can actually call the supper().__init__() with different parameters depending on what A recieves

I did it and it works, I will write an answer on this, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can actually be solved by using a sub-class instead of a wrapper (Thanks @tripleee)
I overlooked this option because the parent class had to be instantiated differently depending on the child class parameters. But this can be done as follow:

```
import B

class A(B):
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        if parameter == 1:
            super().__init__(x=1)
        elif parameter == 2:
            super().__init__(y=2, z=3)
        else:
            raise ValueError
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if the "child class" adds nothing but an ``__init__`` like this, you can just use a function.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi indeed. this is a simplified version, in fact there are plenty of x, y, z parameters that I want to hide from outside A, and A needs to fit in a framework  that I cannot modify, that uses classes

Answer (score 3):

The sentence "methods `B.__enter__()` and `B.__exit__()` should not be used outside B" is meant to teach newbie programmers how to properly use `with` statement.

However, you are *implementing* it. What you are doing is perfectly acceptable and correct. In fact I do not know of any better way either.